# I can't get my histogram to display solid bars instead it comes up with individual lines for each data point

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, data-analysis

I am completely new to python and I have been trying to create a histogram from a random 200x200 numpy array. I have included the code below:

```py
random=np.random.normal(size=(200,200)) 
print(random)
plt.hist(random, bins=10, histtype='bar')
plt.savefig('histogram.jpeg')
```

The graph I get from this code looks like this:

[image]

I cannot get the graph to form bars for the amount of bins and I don't know why.

In addition to this I need to overplot the mean, median and the mean +/- 1 sigma(68% confidence  interval) values as vertical lines. I know you can get the mean and median values using the code below but i'm not sure how to overplot these values as vertical lines.

median = np.median(random)
mean = np.mean(random)

Comment: you are making 200 histograms, each with 10 bars, one for each row of data you are passing in.

Comment: Thanks! How would you alter the code to fix this problem?

Comment: depends what you want.   If you just want to histogram all the data, just flatten the data: `plt.hist(X.flat, bins=10)`

Comment: Something unrelated:  to save an image of a plot, it is strongly recommended to use the `.png` format instead of  `.jpeg`.  `.png` takes advantage of many pixels having the same color, while `.jpeg` smears pixels out, supposing nearby pixels have similar but slightly different colors (such as in photos).